# Hitting a Target

Tags: probability

If the probability of hitting a target is $1/5$, and 10 shots are fired independently, what is the probability of the target being hit at least twice?

Let $X$ be the number of times the target is hit. We want to find $P(X \geq 2)$. So $$P(X \geq 2) = 1-P(X < 2)$$

$$ = 1- \binom{10}{0} (0.2)^{0} (0.8)^{10}-\binom{10}{1} (0.2)^{1}(0.8)^{9}$$

Would that be correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and I am pleased that you figured out that it is easier to calculate the complementary probability instead of adding up $P\{X = 2\} + P\{X = 3\} + \cdots + P\{X = 10\}$

Answer (score 3):

One way to check theory is to simulate the problem. The code snippet below (using Octave) gives the empirical value of $0.62980$ which is comparable to the answer you have: $0.62419$ (See computation at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-+binom%5B10%2C0%5D+%280.2%29%5E%7B0%7D+%280.8%29%5E%7B10%7D-binom%5B10%2C1%5D+%280.2%29%5E%7B1%7D%280.8%29%5E%7B9%7D)).

Of course, simulations like the one below are no *guarantee* that your theoretical answer is correct. However, at the very least they can help rule out incorrect answers and serve as a secondary check to your theoretical analysis.

> ```
> function ev = ProbEst()
>
> # Probability of hit is 1/5
> probHit = 1/5;
>
> totalIter = 10000;
> noShots = 10;
>
> # Counter to track if the event of interest
> # has occurred 
> eventOccurred = 0;
>
> # Set seed of random number generator
> rand("state",[11;22;3209;42038021;11]);
>
> for iter =1:totalIter
>     targetHit = 0;
>     for shot = 1:noShots
>         if (rand(1,1) < probHit)
>             targetHit += 1;
>         endif
>     endfor 
>     if (targetHit >= 2)  
>         eventOccurred += 1;
>     endif
> endfor
>
> # Output empirical probability to console
> eventOccurred/totalIter
>
> endfunction
> ```

Comment: So this does nothing except say "I can't say your result is wrong".

Comment: It is a reality check, or would be if tards had bothered to estimate the size of the sampling error in his/her estimate (looks as though it ought to be $\sim \pm 1$ in the second digit). When you have to do this sort of thing for real it is always a good idea to conduct some sort of reality check. It also shows a horrible example of Octave/Matlab un-vectorised code, but I suppose that could be to make it comprehensible to the uninitiated.